# Add elements to two-dimensionals dynamical table

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, output, free

There is two-dimensional, dynamical allocated table. Put elements inside to table and print them. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **tab;
    int ROWS=3;
    int COLUMNS=5;
    tab = (int**) malloc(ROWS * sizeof(int*));
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<ROWS; ++i)
    {
        tab[i] = (int*)malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(int));
    }

    i=0;
    int j=0;
    for(;i<ROWS;++i)
    {
        for(;j<COLUMNS;++j)
        {
            tab[i][j]=6;
        }
    }

    i=0; j=0;
    for(;i<ROWS;++i)
    {
        for(;j<COLUMNS;++j)
        {
            printf("%i ", tab[i][j]);
        }
    }

    i=0;
    for(;i<ROWS;++i)
    {
        free(tab[i]);
    }
    free(tab);
}
```

Output Only one row?:

6 6 6 6 6

Output should looks like! (3 rows with 5 columns of 'six'):

6 6 6 6 6

6 6 6 6 6

6 6 6 6 6

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `for(;j<COLUMNS;++j)` --> `for(j = 0;j<COLUMNS;++j)`

Comment: This would be why the first clause of the for loop exists - leave it blank at your own peril. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize inner loop from zero.

```
 for(;i<ROWS;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COLUMNS;++j)
        { //^^^ Initialize j = 0
            tab[i][j]=6;
        }
    }

    i=0; j=0;
    for(;i<ROWS;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COLUMNS;++j)
        { //^^^ Initialize j = 0
            printf("%i ", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```